# existence of $DLOGTIME$-complete problems

Tags: computational-complexity

Just curious - is there any problem that can be considered as $DLOGTIME$-complete? Or if not, has it been proven that there does not exist a complete class? (By being complete, I mean that it has lower time/space reduction available - as used conventionally.)

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quinn, [cstheory.se] is for research level questions, non-research level questions in TCS should be directed to [cs.se] in place of [cstheory.se].

Comment: @Kaveh Good to know. Thanks.